# iterate through ordered dict forward only

Tags: python

I am trying to do something like this:

```
## a is a dataframe ##
## b is a ordered dictionary ##
for row in a.itertuples():
    while True:
        try:
            next_iter = next(b.keys())
        else:
            break
        if b[next_iter].method == 'run' and row.method == 'run:
            print(True)
            break
```

But I'm getting TypeError:

> TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 next(dict_by_trigger.keys())
>
> TypeError: 'odict_keys' object is not an iterator

What's the best way to create this iteration such that I only loop through the dictionary keys and dataframe once?

Comment: Since your code does not work, it's difficult to tell what you are actually trying to achieve. Can you explain what "something like this" is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you can't call `next` on the return value of `b.keys()`. I think the `try-else` logic for that is a little excessive anyway. How about just looping through your dict like this:

```
for row in a.itertuples():
    for k, v in b.items():
        if v.method == 'run' and row.method == 'run':
            print(True)
            break
```

EDIT: Or are you trying to find the object in each iterable whose method is run? In that case, I wouldn't embed the loops, I'd just use two different loops. This would be O(N^2) vs the better O(N).

```
df_row = None
odict_val = None

for row in a.itertuples():
    if row.method == 'run':
        df_row = row
        break

for v in b.values():
    if v.method == 'run':
        odict_val = v
        break
```

Comment: Or `if v.method == row.method == 'run':` but I'm not sure this is what OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you are trying to achive, but as I understand your question, you want to loop both the dataframe and the dictionary just *once* i.e. you do not want to restart the inner loop for each element in the data frame but continue where you left in the previous iteration. In this case, create an iterator of the dictionaries elements using the `iter` function.

Simplified example:

```
A = range(10)
B = range(10)
itB = iter(B)
for a in A:
    for b in itB:
        if b % 2 == 0:
            print(a, b)
            break
```

This yield the pairs `0 0`, `1 2`, `2 4`, `3 6`, `4 8`.